# after software update, website not accessible

Tags: 13.04, networking, firewall, iptables

I just applied a bunch of recommended updates this morning (which seems to have upgraded the kernel to 3.8.0-32.47), and suddenly I cannot connect to the machine on port 80 (http) or 22 (ssh).  Ping still works.  In addition, my syslog and kern.log are filling up with messages like

```
Oct 22 10:43:27 mu kernel: [ 4041.036862] Inbound IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=6c:62:6d:c8:b0:d3:18:03:73:34:81:b8:08:00 SRC=192.168.212.43 DST=192.168.212.56 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=17389 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59502 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

I can connect to the web server locally, so this smells like a firewall issue to me.  I've tried:

- doing "reset firewall" from inside GUFW
- doing "sudo ufw allow 80" and "sudo ufw allow 22" from the command line

and that is not working.  So I went and looked at "sudo iptables -L", and I'm getting this, but I don't understand the output (I have hidden my employer's domain with "example.com")

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  ad1.example.com  anywhere             tcpflags:! FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     udp  --  ad1.example.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  ad2.example.com  anywhere             tcpflags:! FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     udp  --  ad2.example.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  ad3.example.com  anywhere             tcpflags:! FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     udp  --  ad3.example.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 10/sec burst 5
DROP       all  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255     
DROP       all  --  anywhere             192.168.212.255     
DROP       all  --  base-address.mcast.net/8  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/8 
DROP       all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             0.0.0.0             
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
LSI        all  -f  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 10/min burst 5
INBOUND    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level info prefix "Unknown Input"
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?  Or how to fix it?  (I think I'm about to learn a lot about iptables.)

UPDATE

Unsurprisingly, other services on the machine (MySQL) are not responding either.  nmap is telling me that the ports are open, tho

```
chris@mu:/var/log$ nmap 192.168.212.56

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-22 10:55 EDT
Nmap scan report for sentry (192.168.212.56)
Host is up (0.00030s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
3306/tcp open  mysql
5666/tcp open  nrpe
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the command `sudo iptables -F` which can be used to erase all the firewall rules (it's a dev machine, so I don't really care), and used it. Now everything is accessible.